# Replacing NSMutableArray with NSObject and reading it in a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, uipickerview

I'm trying to make it so that when I select an owner of a ship on a picherWheel, I get their boats up in a tableView. Currently, I am doing it through feeding a NSMutableArray with if-else series on the picker, like this

```
-(void)updatePicker
{
NSString *boatsFromOwner = [boatOwners objectAtIndex:[shipOwners selectedRowInComponent:0]];

boatsForOwner = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if ([boatsFromOwner isEqualToString:@"Owner1"]) {
    [self.boatsForOwner addObject:@"Titanic1"];
    [self.boatsForOwner addObject:@"Titanic2"];
    [self.boatsForOwner addObject:@"Titanic3"];
    [self.boatsForOwner addObject:@"Titanic4"];
    [self.boatsForOwner addObject:@"Titanic5"];
    [self.boatsForOwner addObject:@"Titanic6"];
    [self.boatsForOwner addObject:@"Titanic7"];
    }
if ([boatsFromOwner isEqualToString:@"Owner2"]) {
    [self.boatsForOwner addObject:@"Titanic1"];
    [self.boatsForOwner addObject:@"Titanic2"];
    [self.boatsForOwner addObject:@"Titanic3"];


    }
```

and then reading it to a tableView like this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [boatsForOwner count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];   


cell.nameLabel.text = [boatsForOwner objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.moreInfoLabel.text = [boatsForOwner objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.boatsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"boatInfoSegue" sender:cell];


[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

Now, this works okay. But I figured it would be smart to use NSObjects to store information about the ships, since I will be needing it multiple places. So I made a few ship objects, like this:

```
cargoShips* Titanic = [[cargoShips alloc]init];
Titanic.name = @"Titanic1";
Titanic.size = @"1000";
Titanic.owner = @"Owner1";
cargoShips* Titanic2 = [[cargoShips alloc]init];
Titanic2.name = @"Titanic2";
Titanic2.size = @"2000";
Titanic2.owner = @"Owner2";
```

This logs correctly and works great. Here's the first question:

**1)** How can I link objects on the pickerWheel to the *.owner, so when I select 'Owner1' on the wheel I get all the boats tagged with `*.owner = @"Owner1"`?

**2)** How do I populate a UITableView with the *.name of those boats?

**3)** And when the table is loaded with these objects, how can I send a message to the target view on what object sent it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pretty easy and straight forward.. Simply use the objects of class CargoShips you have created.. And do it this way..

```
-(void)updatePicker
{
NSString *boatsFromOwner = [boatOwners objectAtIndex:[shipOwners selectedRowInComponent:0]];

boatsForOwner = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if ([boatsFromOwner isEqualToString:@"Owner1"]) {
  cargoShips* Titanic = [[cargoShips alloc]init];
  Titanic.name = @"Titanic1";
  Titanic.size = @"1000";
  Titanic.owner = @"Owner1";

  [self.boatsForOwner addObject:Titanic];

  Titanic = [[cargoShips alloc]init];
  Titanic.name = @"Titanic2";
  Titanic.size = @"2000";
  Titanic.owner = @"Owner2";

  [self.boatsForOwner addObject:Titanic];

  Titanic = [[cargoShips alloc]init];
  Titanic.name = @"Titanic3";
  Titanic.size = @"3000";
  Titanic.owner = @"Owner3";

  [self.boatsForOwner addObject:Titanic];

}else if ([boatsFromOwner isEqualToString:@"Owner2"]) {
  cargoShips* Titanic = [[cargoShips alloc]init];
  Titanic.name = @"Titanic1";
  Titanic.size = @"1000";
  Titanic.owner = @"Owner1";

  [self.boatsForOwner addObject:Titanic];

  Titanic = [[cargoShips alloc]init];
  Titanic.name = @"Titanic2";
  Titanic.size = @"2000";
  Titanic.owner = @"Owner2";

  [self.boatsForOwner addObject:Titanic];

}

}
```

and in TableView delegate functions you can use the following code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];   

cargoShips* Titanic=[boatsForOwner objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//You can get the object reference like this 
cell.nameLabel.text = Titanic.name;
cell.moreInfoLabel.text = Titanic.owner;

return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{

cargoShips* Titanic=[boatsForOwner objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //Use the Titanic object for further processing..
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.boatsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"boatInfoSegue" sender:cell];


[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: The 'Titanic' Variable, can you go a little bit more indepth on this? Awesome answer otherwise, but I did not quite understand that part. Say I have a target view with three labels for size, name and owner. Can I just go ahead and say `nameLabel.text = @"%@", Titanic.name;` and Titanic.name would be the one I selected in the table?

Comment: Just use the objects added in the array. Say you want to show info by selecting the table cell on the screen, you will use the tableview didselect and from there you will get specific object added to the array like this cargoShips* Titanic=[boatsForOwner objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; now, just use the object Titanic to show the description if you have view defined outside the current controller, or you can declare a global variable say cargoShips* selectedTitanic; & can use like this self.selectedTitanic=[boatsForOwner objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  Btw you can vote up if u like my answer..